# Upload Local Laravel Project to Server

Tags: php, laravel, hosting

I've created a Laravel 5.3 project on my local apache server(XAMPP) and it works fine with login and registration.

However, when I upload(via FTP) to my server(the server is 000webhosting) and try to do login it returns an error saying:

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 119:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

I've already changed the .env to match the server DB's info, and just in case I also changed the `config/database.php` to also match. But it still appears like that?

Do you know exactly everything I have to change in my project so it can work on the server?

Comment: Are you sure all credentials, server address, port, db name etc all match?

Comment: May be your database server is offline.

Comment: @ITDesigns.eu Yes, they all match

Comment: @HimanshuRaval I'm pretty sure it's online, but I'll double check

Comment: @AdamSilva Try to change DB_HOST to either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` check which one will work, also make sure the port number is correct usually its `3306`

Comment: @HimanshuRaval Connection refused would not be thrown if DB was offline

Comment: @Neal some webhosters make funny DB privilege auto setup and sometimes forget to create localhost host for 127.0.0.1, but 000webhosting is not one of them... I would double check privileges for the user you are trying to connect with and CONNECTION TYPE.

Comment: May be the port number on live can be different for db

Answer (score 0):

May be Your database password changed in live. update  .env file